# ion-tabs not at the bottom (Android)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have an issue that only shows up in the Android version of my app. The iOS version is fine and when ran in the web view (chrome) it is also fine. It is the position of the ion-tabs.

In iOS they are at the very bottom of the screen.

[image: iOS Image]

but in Android it is like this.

[image: Android View]

Now, I presume this is some sort of 'Safe Area'. I tried setting the '--ion-safe-area-bottom' variable like I do for iOS but on Android...nothing.

Any ideas? I have read it could be something to do with the built in web view in the android app but no solutions. Help much appreciated.